# Installing ubuntu without hiding an already installed windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have a bootable flash drive containing a ubuntu installer. I want to install ubuntu on my system without hiding windows 7. Last time when I installed windows on my system it hid the ubuntu boot menu.

What steps I can take to make sure that this time, installing ubuntu won't hide/remove my windows 7 ?

Comment: I think windows hide ubuntu, but ubuntu won't hide windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you install Ubuntu on a separate/empty partition, Ubuntu will install a boot loader which will let you choose which OS you want to boot.

If you don't have a separate partition and don't know how to repartition your system i recommend [wubi.exe](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows). Wubi will let you install Ubuntu from Windows. It will create a big File in which Ubuntu is installed and set up the boot loader. This is the easiest way to install Ubuntu next to an existing Windows installation, but the performance is less good than if it is installed on a separate partition.